# Cannot customize interactive javascript content

Tags: javascript, php, plugins, moodle

We are using Moodle version 3.5 and using H5P plugin for interactive videos. We need add another action on submit button

Please check link https://h5p.org/interactive-video. After answering questions, a summary screen appears like below:

[image: Summary screen]

```js
<script>

function checkclick()
{
    $(document).ready(function(){

        $(".h5p-interactive-video-endscreen-submit-button").click(function(){
            alert("submitted");

        });
     });
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    iframe=H5P.$body.contents();
    iframe.find(".h5p-interactive-video-endscreen-submit-button").click(function(){
          alert("hello");
    });
});

// H5P.$body.contents().find(".h5p-interactive-video-endscreen-submit-button")

// $(document).ready(function(){
//        var button= H5P.$body.contents().find(".h5p-interactive-video-endscreen-submit-button");
//     button.attr("id","myclass");
//        console.log(button);
// });

</script>
```

Have tried above-mentioned techniques to get the alert on click of the button but didn't succeed.

Answer (score 0):

change this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    iframe=H5P.$body.contents();
    iframe.find(".h5p-interactive-video-endscreen-submit-button").click(function(){
      alert("hello");
    });
});
```

to this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    iframe=H5P.$body.contents();
    $(document).on('click',function(){
        if(iframe.find(".h5p-interactive-video-endscreen-submit-button").is(":hover")){
          alert('hello');
        }
    });
});
```

i usually do this if elements click is not detectable and it works.

Comment: Nope, its not working. Basically it is an iframe content which is changing dynamically and javascript is not picking that i guess.

Comment: could you add H5P variable . I can't understand what it is.

Comment: iframe=H5P.$body.contents();
    iframe.find(".h5p-interactive-video-endscreen-submit-button");

with this code you can find the element i want to target which is nested in child nodes.

Answer (score 0):

H5P uses xAPI statements that are triggered by different user actions. You can listen to the *completed* statement that's fired by H5P.InteractiveVideo when the submit button is hit. This way, you don't have to rely on the DOM.

```
document.addEventListener('readystatechange', function() {
  // Run when document ready state is complete
  if (document.readyState !== 'complete') {
    return;
  }

  // H5P emits xAPI statements that can be tracked using H5P.externalDispatcher
  if (!H5P || !H5P.externalDispatcher) {
    console.warn('Cannot use H5P.externalDispatcher');
    return;
  }

  H5P.externalDispatcher.on('xAPI', function(event) {
    const xAPI = event.data.statement;

    /*
     * The submit button og H5P.InteractiveVideo triggers an xAPI event with the
     * verb 'completed' for the context of IV, so we can check for xAPI+
     * statements for that.
     *
     * verb.id is a mandatory property of xAPI statements, context is optional,
     * hence the checks.
     */
    const verbIsAnswered = xAPI.verb.id === 'http://adlnet.gov/expapi/verbs/completed';
    const contextIsIV = xAPI.context && xAPI.context.contextActivities && xAPI.context.contextActivities.category &&
        xAPI.context.contextActivities.category.length > 0 &&
        xAPI.context.contextActivities.category[0].id &&
        xAPI.context.contextActivities.category[0].id.indexOf('H5P.InteractiveVideo') !== -1;

    if (!verbIsAnswered || !contextIsIV) {
      return
    }

    // Your function
  });
});
```

Instead of hardcoding that into the official sources (which I assume you did because of the script tag in your example), you should use the *alter_scripts* hook that H5P offers. It allows you to add custom scripts to particular H5P content when needed, e.g. only to H5P.InteractiveVideo. Please compare https://h5p.org/moodle-customization. Using the hook you will not be required to add your changes again and again whenever there's an update of IV.